# Blueimp fileupload : How to force the form action path instead url option?

Tags: php, upload, directory, blueimp

I have a page that manages uploads in specific folders. On this page, there is a upload form for each folder. So, here is my javascript file (main.js), each form has the ".fileupload" class :

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

$('.fileupload').fileupload();

$('.fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

$.ajax({
    url: $('.fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('.fileupload')[0]
}).always(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
});

});
```

To tell the script to catch and upload files in specific folder, I add a variable called "folder" in the action path that I will get in my index.php upload script. Here is my HTML :

```
<form class="fileupload" action="//mywebsite.com/server/php/index.php?folder=<?=$folder?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

Here is my PHP (server/php/index.php) :

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
    'upload_dir' => "/home/mywebsite/public_html/users/" . $_GET['folder'],
    'upload_url' => "//mywebsite.com/users/" . $_GET['folder']
));
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work. I mean, images located in each folder are not shown and the upload doesn't start anyway.

My question is how to force (through my HTML/PHP) the upload script path with specific variable (here "folder") encapsulated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `<?=$folder?>` does but I suspect that's the problem. Why not generate the action link dynamically in your JS function? Something like:

```
var folder = 'folder1'; //<-- insert folder name here
var actionlink = '//mywebsite.com/server/php/index.php?folder=' + folder;
$('.fileupload').attr('action', actionlink);
```

Comment: <?=$folder?> echoes the folder name (in PHP).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Xavier, I just learned about that shorthand yesterday